# Adding speed boost to 2D player during roll animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

```
    private Rigidbody2D R2D;

  void Start()
    {
        R2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

            float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            R2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Roll"))
        {
            float rollSpeed = 20;
            anim.SetBool("Roll", true);
            R2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * rollSpeed, R2D.velocity.y);

        }
```

All im trying to do is add a boost to the players speed when they press the roll button, the animations all work, the only problem here is the speed of the player.

I want to make a nice boost to the players speed during the roll animation, which is controlled by the Roll boolean inside if statement above.

Neither 'Unity' or 'Unity2D' tags exist, and I lack the rep to make them.

Entire code : http://www.pastebucket.com/553044

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly using `Rigidbody2D`, one should never directly modify velocity or transform (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html).

Instead, do the following:

```
Vector2 force = 'your force';
R2D.AddForce(force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html